# Change href on small device

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone Im a new web programmer.
I dont know how to solve this problem. I need to change an href on <400px screen cause I redesigned the homepage for smartphone. In CSS I hid the original page and shown this last. Appreciate your help. Thanks
Here is my code:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changelink(){
    var link=document.getElementById("scrollhome");

    if(document.width<400px){
    link.href="#smartphone";
    }
  }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-1 col-xs-3 scatola">
   <a class="scroll" href="#slide1" id="scrollhome"><div class="box-piccolo bordo" style="background-color:#4D4543">
       <i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-4x" style="color:#fff"></i>
   </div></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without `jquery`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changelink(){
    var width = document.body.clientWidth;
    var link=document.getElementById("scrollhome");

    if(width < 400){
       link.href="#smartphone";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks man. If I want to use jquery how can I do it?I have jquery.js for other things so I can use it.

Comment: Ops Im so sorry...I dont know jquery yet...thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to change your href

```
 if ($(window).width() < 400)
 {
     link.href="#smartphone";
     return;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function changelink(){
    var link=document.getElementById("scrollhome");

    if( window.innerWidth<400px)
       link.href="#smartphone"; 

    return false;
  }
</script>
```